# jQuery - insert value into <input value="">

Tags: jquery

I have the following script that dynamically builds text fields with a value from other input element.
The value is displayed on the screen but it doesn't get inserted into `value=""` as inspected in the dev tool. I need the value to be inserted as `value=""` so that the form data can be persisted.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(event) {
  $("fieldset").append($('<input>').prop('type', 'text').val($('#entry').val()));
});
```

[image: See my image]

Comment: `$('<input>').attr('value', $('#entry').val())`

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about `attr`. If you make this as an answer, I can settle this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Use:

```
 $('<input>').attr('value', $('#entry').val())
```

Comment: we can use `$("input")` also without `<` and `>` and `input` with `$("input").val($('#entry').val())` also

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(event) {
    $("fieldset").append($("input[type = 'text']")).val($('#entry').val());
    });
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: My original question uses val() but it doesn't create value attribute neither assign value into it.